# d3 v4: Stacking nested data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bunch of data that can be nested into a few categories, e.g.:

```
{id: 1, type: A},
{id: 2, type: A},
{id: 1, type: B},
{id: 1, type: A},
{id: 2, type: B}
```

Nesting this data on `id` gives me nested data with `id` as the key and a `values` array which contains all original values. What I need is a stacked chart showing that id 1 has two type A and one type B occurrences, id 2 has one of each, etc. This is the code I'm using:

```
var nested = d3.nest()
                .key( function(d) {
                    return d.Id
                })
                .entries(data);

var stack = d3.stack()
                .keys(['A','B'])
                .offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand);
```

I want these as percentages hence the `stackOffsetExpand`. However this is giving me null stack values, presumably because the `type` field that I want the stack function to use is hidden inside the `values` array. Using the `.value` function of the `stack` call I can see that the data it's seeing is indeed the whole chunk of data for each nested array (i.e. `key: 1, values: [{all objects with id 1 here}]`). I just don't know how to use that function to tell it to start counting on the `type` property...

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to calculate the percentage from your data. I'm setting the keys first and then rolling up the values in the `nest` function using `rollup`. Then, I'm calculating the percentage for each key after that.

```
var raw_data = [{id: 1, type: "A"},
{id: 2, type: "A"},
{id: 1, type: "B"},
{id: 1, type: "A"},
{id: 2, type: "B"}];

var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.id;})
    .rollup(function(d) { return d.length; })
    .entries(raw_data);

    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.percentage = d.value  / raw_data.length;
    console.log(d.key + ": " + d.percentage*100);
});
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/do4ym1L2/